# How do I use llvm-profdata in Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I have a simple question: how do I use the `llvm-profdata` binary provided by XCode's Command Line Tools in the terminal?

I have installed the Command Line Tools and could see the binary in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/`, like this:

```
$ ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ | grep llvm
llvm-cov
llvm-profdata
```

I know I could make it work by adding the path to `/etc/paths`, but I'm not sure what other side effect will occur if I do that.

For reference, here's my current `/etc/paths`:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I also have `homebrew` installed, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking installing XCode and/or the command line tools should have added those paths to your shell path variable. Odd that it didn't. Perhaps someone with more familiarity with XCode can help with that.

You *could* just type the whole path to the app every time you want to use it. But that would be a PITA.

Adding the path to those apps does not affect anything else, it only gives you easy access to the apps/commands in the path. If there are apps there that are literal duplicates of others in your path that might be a problem but all adding to your path variable does is tell the terminal to "look in this location for commands too."

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the `xcrun` tool which will be in your path.

```
$ xcrun llvm-profdata <args>
```

The `xcrun` tool will execute the tool from the currently selected developer tools installation.

If you have Xcode installed you can select which developer tools are used with `xcode-select`. For example, if you have a beta version installed you can use that version of the command line tools with:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app"
```

and switch back with

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode.app"
```

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?